# CMD result into a DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlcmd

I'm trying to create an installer that restores a Database and I want to return the results from the cmd command `sqlcmd -L` into a drop down select on a button click event.

Is there any possible way to achieve that without sending the output of the command into a `file.txt` and read each line afterwards?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string command;
    command = "sqlcmd -L " ;

    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();

       //Get the result and populate the drop down
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but the `Process` class has a `StandardOutput` property that allows you to get the data dumped to the standard output (usually the console) by the process. So after the process has finished (use `proc.WaitForExit()` for that) you can just do:

```
string processOutput = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Then if you need to process each line separately, you can do:

```
var lines = processOutput.Split(
    new[] {Environment.NewLine},
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach(var line in lines) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but i`m looking for returning the output into a list of strings, each element of the list corresponding to a line from the output.Tahnks

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell you are talking about interprocess communication.  There are a whole bunch of mechanisms available for this, have a look here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx